What is the ideal way to save a large and ever-growing encrypted logseq folder with version control?
I am using logseq together with cryptomator.
I have a large graph now that I would very much not like to lose.
Up to this point I have used git in the encrypted folder.
The main issue right now is that this folder is about 8GB and it contains many files above 100mb. Essentially, these seem to come from documents (pdfs mostly) that are referenced from the pages in logseq.
This folder will only grow in size in time.
Github does not recommend repositories this large.
Also, I have to use Github's LFS to be able to push. I don't use this frequently in general so it is always time-consuming to relearn how to do it exactly.
I also periodically save a copy of the encrypted folder to cloud storage.
What is the ideal solution to safeguarding this encrypted folder with version control?
